# how do i make the code differentiate between several buttons in my todoapp?

Tags: javascript, html, input, innerhtml

hi so i am trying to make "todoapp" but it is not working as intended: if there are more then one task
in a list edit and delete buttons are bugged. please help. how do i make the code differentiate between several tasks?
my code:

````
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="text" value="">
    <button id="button" type="button" onclick="add()">add</button>
    <div id="ss"></div>
    <script>
        function add(){
        document.getElementById("ss").innerHTML +=  document.getElementById("text").value + "<button id='edit' onclick='edit()'>edit</button>"+"<button id='edit' onclick='del()'>delete</button>"+"<br>";
        }
        function edit(){
            document.getElementById("edit").outerHTML =  "<input type='text' id='etext' value=''>"+"<button id='done' onclick='done()'>done</button>";
        }
        function done(){
            document.getElementById("ss").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("etext").value + "<button id='edit' onclick='edit()'>edit</button>"+"<button id='edit' onclick='del()'>delete</button>"+"<br>";;
        }
        function del(){
            document.getElementById("ss").innerHTML = "<div></div>";
        }
    </script>    
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: You should pass something unique such as index or id of task to delete/edit/modify it. Your logic should search for specific todo from list and perform desired action only on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate and use a UL

```js
const buttons = `<button type="button" class='edit'>edit</button> <button type="button" class="del">delete</button>`

const ul = document.getElementById("ss");
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("ss").innerHTML += `<li>
      <span>${document.getElementById("text").value}</span> ${buttons}
    </li>`
})
ul.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("edit") && !document.getElementById('etext')) {
    const li = tgt.closest("li")
    li.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='etext' value='" + li.querySelector('span').textContent + "'><button type='button' class='done'>done</button>";
  } else if (tgt.classList.contains("done")) {
    tgt.closest("li").innerHTML = `${document.getElementById("etext").value} ${buttons}`
  } else if (tgt.classList.contains("del")) {
    tgt.closest("li").remove();
  }
})
document.getElementById("delAll").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ul.innerHTML = "";
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" value="">
<button id="add" type="button">add</button><button id="delAll" type="button">Delete all</button><hr/>
<ul id="ss"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the id, because they are not unique when adding dynamically identical list items. I tweaked edit and done function to make it functional. Hopefully it helps you further.

```js
function add() {
  document.getElementById("ss").innerHTML += "<div class='entry'><span class='value'>" + document.getElementById("text").value + "</span><button onclick='edit(this)'>edit</button>" + "<button onclick='del(this)'>delete</button><br></div>";
}

function edit(elem) {
  elem.outerHTML = "<input type='text' value=''>" + "<button onclick='done(this)'>done</button>";
}

function done(elem) {
  let children = elem.parentElement.childNodes;
  let spanElem, inputElem;
  for (var i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (children[i].tagName == "SPAN") {
        spanElem = children[i];
    }
    if (children[i].tagName == "INPUT") {
        inputElem = children[i];
    }
  }
  spanElem.innerHTML = inputElem.value;
  elem.outerHTML = "<button onclick='edit(this)'>edit</button>";
  elem.remove();
  inputElem.remove();
}

function del(elem) {
  elem.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="text" value="">
  <button id="button" type="button" onclick="add()">add</button>
  <div id="ss"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your BRs stay behind

Comment: Ok, thanks, I moved the break into the parent div.